# Rails: default serializers and safe_params to all fields in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

In my Rails / Angular app I am passing data to the front-end via Rails serializers, and permitting updates to fields via params.permit.

I understand that part of the purpose of the serializer/safe_params is to carefully control what comes and goes to the server. However, for most models, I am finding I need to include all fields.

Is there a metaprogramming or other method where the body of the serailizer and safe_params can simple expose / accept all fields on the model, including virtual fields?

Example code

**serializer**

```
class BatchSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
        :description,       
        :details,          
        :user_id,             
        :name,                
        :dataset,             
        :dataset_id,          
        :pairs_per_sequence,  
        :pairs_per_bp,         
        :batch_type,           
        :overlap_size,        
        :padding,             
        :assembly_id,          
        :multiplex_tolerance,  
        :run_id,                
        :snp_mask,             
        :primer3_parameter_id, 
        :specificity_check,
        :batch_status,
        :avoid_cross_primers,
        :temperature_similarity,
        :gibbs_free_energy,
        :base_termination,
        :wet_lab
end
```

**controller safe_params**

```
 def safe_params
params.permit(:id,
        :description,       
        :details,          
        :user_id,             
        :name,                
        :dataset,             
        :dataset_id,          
        :pairs_per_sequence,  
        :pairs_per_bp,         
        :batch_type,           
        :overlap_size,        
        :padding,             
        :assembly_id,          
        :multiplex_tolerance,  
        :run_id,                
        :snp_mask,             
        :primer3_parameter_id, 
        :specificity_check,
        :avoid_cross_primers,
        :temperature_similarity,
        :gibbs_free_energy,
        :base_termination,
        :wet_lab_result)
  end
```

**EDIT**

This post offers an answer to half of the problem: permit all
[Rails 4 Strong parameters : permit all attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033908/rails-4-strong-parameters-permit-all-attributes)

So how would I automatically serialize all fields?

Comment: You could (re)define the `as_json` method to define which attributes you want serialized on the model when `to_json` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply stop passing in a serializer, Rails will use the default serializer that renders all attributes by default.

eg, suppose you have a model called `MyObject`, you can render with:

```
render :json => my_object
```

re: permitting all attributes - you can take a look at [Rails 4 Strong parameters : permit all attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033908/rails-4-strong-parameters-permit-all-attributes) for that.